# Don't blur button if specific element is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple drop down menu that is shown while certain `<button id="example">` is focused. Inside such drop down is an input for a simple list search. 
When clicked on, it triggers a blur event to happen on a button, hence hides drop down menu.

Is there a way to ignore it somehow on click so that the blur event doesn't occur for a button?

Comment: Almost 5000 REP and no [mcve] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will always make a blur event when you do that.

What you can do is to extend the visibility of the drop down menu so it's visible when either the button **or** the menu itself has focus; or simply hide the menu when a click outside of the button and the menu is made. There are plenty of way to do it.